# Is it possible to replace a WebView with Chromium (CefBrowser) in an existing XCode project (OS X)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview, chromium-embedded

I have to switch from a normal WebView to Chromium because this solution is said to work much better with a special database.
I downloaded the CefSimpleSample and I think I understand how it works.

I included the used libraries but I can't get the project working as it's supposed to be.

Does anybody have experience with Cef in an OS X - XCode - Application?

Cheers

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I used a sample application from cef and altered it to create my own.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html) project is something you can try. It uses a dedicated CEF runtime: